# Quotient Spaces (with respect to the Kernel of a Differential Operator)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, orthogonality

I have some continuous, linear, elliptic linear differential operator $O: H^1(\Omega) \to X_0^*$.

$X_0^*$ is the dual space of $X = \{x \in H^1(\Omega): x=0 \mbox{ on } \partial \Omega \}$.

The differential equation setup is:

$Ou=f$ in $X^*$

$u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$

The quotient space I am trying to visualize better is defined as
$Q = \{ q-P_{\ker(O)}(q) , q \in X_0 \}$.

$P_{\ker(O)}(q)$ is a projection operator here. It is defined as a mapping from $H^1(\Omega)$ to $\ker(O)$ and is defined as $Pq = \sum_{i=1} ^{dim(\ker(O))} (q,\varphi_i) \varphi_i$
where $\varphi_i$ is an orthonormal basis of $\ker(O)$.

From my understanding of a quotient space, the set $Q$ should be the set of all affine subsets of $X_0$ parallel to $\ker (O)$.

So for example, if $O$ is the Laplacian, then $\ker(O) = $ the set of constant functions. Therefore, $Q$, as I understand it should be all functions in $X_0$ parallel to the constant functions (here we would use the $L^2$ inner product to determine what is parallel).

**Question 1: Is this the right interpretation of a quotient group? Also, based on definitions of quotient groups online I would expect the elements to be $q+P_{\ker(O)}(q)$. Does this make a difference in the interpretation?**

I was confused because later in the same paper that I'm reading they introduce a method and within that method they say "orthogonalize the vectors
to the span of set S by using $g-P_{span(S)} (g)$ for each $g \in S$." This looks just like how they defined the quotient group above. But I thought the quotient group would result in things parallel to the span of S in this setup, not orthogonal.

**Question 2: How can this expression be used to orthogonalize the vectors to the span of set $S$ when it is so close to the definition of a quotient group?**

Comment: "I was confused because later in the same paper that I'm reading [...]"  If you provide a link, or at least name the author and title of the paper, then you may be more likely to get an answer.  For example, maybe people will find the paper itself interesting, and they may be more confident if they can see the full context.

Comment: @RenEhDaycart Oops! Sorry didn't know that I could do that. I was worried about posting the paper and asking people to read into it because I didn't want to come off as not doing enough work to understand my question.  I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were inconsistencies in the post that make it hard to be very precise, but I think I understand the OP's question and let me explain what I perceive to be the difficulty.

What you understand is the more formal way of thinking about the quotient space
$$
H^1(\Omega)/\ker(O),
$$
but since there is an inner product on $H^1(\Omega)$, we can more concretely have an orthogonal decompositon
$$
H^1(\Omega)\cong \ker(O)\oplus \ker(O)^\perp,
$$
so the quotient space is
$$
H^1(\Omega)/\ker(O)\cong \ker(O)^\perp.
$$

Your understanding of $H^1(\Omega)/\ker(O)$ as affine spaces parallel to $\ker(O)$ is correct, but now more concretely you can understand them as points in $\ker(O)^\perp$. (Your affine space now corresponds to its intersection with $\ker(O)^\perp$.) More concretely, the formula is
$$
H^1(\Omega)\to \ker(O)^\perp;\ q\mapsto q-P_{\ker(O)}q. 
$$

Concerning the notation, $q+\ker(O)\in H^1(\Omega)/\ker(O)$ is a coset (this writing is different from your $q+P_{\ker(O)}q$), and now it corresponds to $q-P_{\ker(O)}q$. The notations match since $-P_{\ker(O)}q\in \ker(O)$, and it is this particular choice that makes $q-P_{\ker(O)}q\in \ker(O)^\perp$.

This idea then also explains your second question, since $g-P_{span(S)}g$ is the projection of $g$ to the orthogonal complement of $span(S)$.

Just think about $V={\mathbb R}^2$, the Cartesian plane, and $W={\mathbb R}^1$, the $x$-axis. Then $V/W$ is isomorphic to the $y$-axis, and the map is
$$
(x, y)\mapsto (x, y)-(x, 0) = (0, y).
$$

Comment: Thank you very very much this great explanation! Sorry about the inconsistencies in my original post I was a bit confused at first but this really helped me so much. Thanks again!

Comment: It was a pleasure.